# Como ignorar um arquivo especifico em diretório?

Tags: php

O código abaixo faz a contagem de todos arquivos do meu diretório, mas quero ignorar o arquivo `index.php`

```
$i=0;
foreach (glob ("*.*") as $file){
$a[$i] = $file;
$i++;
}
echo count($a);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o um `if` ou `unset` para ignorar ou remover, respectivamente, o `index` do array.

Exemplo:

```
foreach (glob ("*.*") as $file){
    if ($file != "index.php") {
        $a[] = $file;
    }
}
echo count($a);
```

Caso você queira ignorar todos os `index.php`:

```
foreach (glob ("*.*") as $file){
    if (!preg_match("/index\.php$/", $file)) {
        $a[] = $file;
    }
}
echo count($a);
```

Ou basta remove-lo do array `$a`.

```
foreach (glob ("*.*") as $file){
    $a[] = $file;
}

/* Verifica se o arquivo existe no array */
if (isset($a["index.php"])) {

    /* Caso exista, remove ele. */
    unset($a["index.php"]);
}
echo count($a);
```

Para ignorar dois ou mais arquivos, você utilizar da mesma forma que o primeiro exemplo, porém você utilizar o sinal `||`. Esse sinal na estrutura de condição equivale ao `OU`. Exemplo:

```
foreach (glob ("*.*") as $file){
    /* Se o nome do arquivo for diferente de "index" OU diferente de "config.php , armazena variável $a */
    if ($file != "index.php" || $file != "config.php") {
        $a[] = $file;
    }
}
echo count($a);
```

Porém você também pode utilizar um array com os nomes que você quer ignorar e depois utilizar `in_array` para verificar se esses valores existem, caso existam, você ignora. Exemplo:

```
$filesIgnore = ['index.php', 'config.php'];

foreach (glob ("*.*") as $file){
    /* Se o nome do arquivo não existe na variável $filesIgnora, adiciona ele na variável $a */
    if (!in_array($file, $filesIgnore)) {
        $a[] = $file;
    }
}
echo count($a);
```

Comment: Primeiro exemplo resolveu, maravilha. Agora pintou outra duvida como ignorar 2 arquivos? index.php e config.php

Comment: @Rose editei minha resposta. Adicionei mais alguns exemplos.